# Select a title via an id and get a result without <form> </form>

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, database

I have to make an automatic reply that makes the discussions appear similar, I thought to use the SQL select syntax

```
SELECT *
        FROM thread
        WHERE subject LIKE '%$msg%'
        LIMIT 5
```

I would like to know how I can do something about HTML and PHP LIKE %$variable%

**Example code PHP:**

```
$msgg=htmlspecialchars($_POST['titlerela']);
sql = "SELECT * FROM thread WHERE subject LIKE '%$msg%' LIMIT 5";
```

**Example code HTML:**

```
<span id="titlerela">this is a title...</span>
```

In short I would like to select the title in a discussion and insert it on the like, see if there is a similar title and have it displayed to everyone without using `<form method="" action=""> </form>`, can it be done? If yes how could I do it?

Comment: One option will be to use Ajax

Comment: @Cedric Cholley well i'm not very good with javascript, you can give me an example small small i know how to make it work with the form, but without i don't know, thanks anyway!

Comment: First you need to have look to [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX). Basically it will make a request on the server without reloading the page.

Comment: @Cedric Cholley  Thanks I solved it, I practically connect the page with ajax on the main page, and then through php I used the sessions to connect the pages, after a lot of research and studies, I solved
now what I wanted appears,
that is
I type a text and the results are updated as soon as I release the input, I wanted something that at the same time there are the results, but it's okay, thanks again, everyone for the availability
ps: sorry for my english, i am using google translator